# Making the GoogleApiClient in Android Studio

Tags: android

I am currently attempting to make a GoogleApiClient. (following the tutorial from: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client#start_an_automatically_managed_connection)

However, when I type enableAutoManage, it comes up with an error saying that it is incompatible, and the addApi and other functions don't work at all. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you in advance.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this);
                .addApi(Drive.API);
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE);
                .build();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove extra `";"`

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
       .enableAutoManage(this, this)
       .addApi(Drive.API)
       .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
       .build();
```